# sql select count(* like '%%')/select count(*)

Tags: sql

I want to count the number proportion of paragraphs that have a `blah` somewhere with respect to the total number of paragraphs.

I tried:

```
select 
  (select count(*) from raw_data where lower(Paragraph) like '%blah%') a,
  (select count(*) from raw_data) b, 
  a/b
```

but end up with the following error:

> Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`a`' given input columns: []; line 1 pos 164;

but, if I run

```
select 
  (select count(*) from raw_data where lower(Paragraph) like '%blah%') a,
  (select count(*) from raw_data) b
```

Returns 2 columns with the correct counts:

```
a   b
9   100
```

I would like:

```
a    b    a/b
9    100  0.09
```

Any suggestions

Comment: You can define your subqueries in a where clause each and then assign it temporary names ```select a, b, a/b where a = (..your query here...) and b = (...your other query here...)```

Comment: Unfortunately, the error: `Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`a`' given input columns: []; line 2 pos 6;` popped up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when lower(Paragraph) like '%blah%' then 1 else 0 end) as a,
       count(*) as b,
       avg(case when lower(Paragraph) like '%blah%' then 1.0 else 0 end) as a_b      
from raw_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon's method is the way to go but to make your approach work you'd need

```
select 
  (select count(*) from raw_data where lower(Paragraph) like '%blah%') a,
  (select count(*) from raw_data) b, 
  (select count(*) from raw_data where lower(Paragraph) like '%blah%')/(select count(*) from raw_data) a_b
```

**OR**

```
select a, b, a/b as a_b
from  (select 
      (select count(*) from raw_data where lower(Paragraph) like '%blah%') a,
      (select count(*) from raw_data) b) t
```